# Rbenv permission denied issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vps, ubuntu-14.04, rbenv

I have trouble getting my Rails app running after I deployed this to my DO droplet.
I deployed (and installed everything including *rbenv*) following [this guide](https://gorails.com/deploy/ubuntu/14.04). Rbenv seems to be installed properly but app is not running and nginx error log says "***cannot execute /root/.rbenv/shims/ruby permission denied (13)***"

I can not get the sense of this error, hope anyone can help with that.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like rbenv's installed under root. It should probably be installed under your (or your app user's) home directory, in this case for the user named 'deploy.'

This Passenger configuration line from `nginx.conf` shows where it's expected to live:

```
/home/deploy/.rbenv/shims/ruby
```

So you should probably (re)install rbenv as/under 'deploy.'

Comment: Ok, the only thing I skipped from the guide above, was creating a "deploy" user. So I don't have another user exept root and I did everything as root.

Comment: And my **passanger_ruby** is linked to **root/.rbenv/shims/ruby** in **nginx.conf**

Comment: I see. It still sounds like somebody's trying to do something as a different user, or (otherwise) there's a missing `sudo` somewhere...